# AWS GLUE - SQL server SSL encryption error

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssl, encryption, aws-glue

Im trying to upload data from SQL Server which is in a EC2 instance to RedShift using AWS Glue.

I have created the Connections and Crawlers and its working fine.

Then I created a Job to load the data I got the below error.

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by
>   using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:
>   "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target".

Logs:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2017-10-24-06-24-48.py", line 20, in <module>
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "XXX", table_name = "XXXXXXX", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 508, in from_catalog
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 120, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_source.py", line 36, in getFrame
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1508826088545_0001/container_1508826088545_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.getDynamicFrame.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:1ee3a8e5-a3a1-4871-a94c-28907c04acef
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2392)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1777)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1969)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$getRawConnection$1.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:535)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$getRawConnection$1.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:535)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.catchSSLException(JDBCUtils.scala:514)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.getRawConnection(JDBCUtils.scala:535)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getPrimaryKeys(DataSource.scala:392)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:354)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:45)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:317)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
```

Comment: Same error in AWS Glue when running a job to scrape from a remote SQL Server instance over VPN.  The connection is successful and the crawler scraped the table schema successfully.  Only the job fails.

Comment: Seeing the same problem.  Table is crawled successfully, but ETL jobs fail with the above exception.  Attempted to set `ecrypted=false` on the JDBC connection string, but the connection test stops passing when set.  Hard to tell which version of the sqlserver driver is being used by AWS Glue.

Comment: Im not sure Casey :(

Comment: Hi, This should now be resolved. Can you retry your job?

Comment: Is this something related to ssl?

Comment: Yeah, Its resolved now. But just want to know what was the issue and how they fixed it?